# Change event firing in wordpress

Tags: custom-field, hooks, publish

I have to run a function when a post is published. The function checks a custom meta value and works accordingly. I am using couple of hooks for this purpose:

```
new_to_publish
draft_to_publish
pending_to_publish
auto-draft_to_publish
```

Now, `new_to_publish` and `auto-draft_to_publish` are not working. It looks like these two hooks run much earlier than `add_post_meta` hook. As a result, my function doesn't get any meta value and doesn't work. I tried:

```
add_action('new_to_publish', 'my_custom_function', /*high priority value here*/)
```

But that doesn't work. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Post all of the relevant code please.

Comment: Here you go: http://pastebin.com/cSq9mf0c
`$restricted_domains`  is the protagonist

Comment: Have you tried the generic `transition_post_status` to catch when it changes to "published?" It might run later. http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions

Answer (score 0):

Using `transistion_post_status` I'm able to retrieve post meta.

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'post_published', 10, 3 );

function post_published( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( $old_status != 'publish' && $new_status == 'publish' ) {

    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($meta);
    echo '</pre>';

    die();

    }
}
```